# Scheduled/Delay messaging in Spring AMQP RabbitMq

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I am struggling hard to find out the way for scheduled/Delaying messages in Spring AMQP/Rabbit MQ.
After hell lot of searching still I am not able to do that in Spring AMQP. Can someone please tell me how to do **x-delay** in Spring AMQP.
I want to Delay a message if some exception occurs in the consumer side. RabbitMQ says to add x-delay and install the plugin which I have already done, but still messages is comming immediately without any delay

I am getting this in message
Received <(Body:'[B@60a4ae5f(byte[26])'MessageProperties [headers={x-delay=15000}

```
 @Bean
ConnectionFactory connectionFactory(){

    CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory=new CachingConnectionFactory("127.0.0.1");
    connectionFactory.setUsername("guest");
    connectionFactory.setPassword("guest");
    connectionFactory.setPort(1500);
    connectionFactory.setPublisherReturns(true);
    return connectionFactory;

}

@Bean
Binding binding(@Qualifier("queue")Queue queue, DirectExchange exchange) {
    return new Binding(queue.getName(), Binding.DestinationType.QUEUE, exchange.getName(), queue.getName(), null);
    //return BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(exchange).with(queueName);   
}

@Bean
DirectExchange exchange() {
    DirectExchange exchange=new DirectExchange("delay-exchange");
    return exchange;
}
```

Consumer---
    @Override

```
public void onMessage(Message message, Channel channel) throws Exception {

    System.out.println("Received <" + message+ ">" +rabbitTemplate);

    if(i==1){
        AMQP.BasicProperties.Builder props = new AMQP.BasicProperties.Builder();
        Map<String,Object> headers = message.getMessageProperties().getHeaders();
        headers.put("x-delay", 15000);
        props.headers(headers);
        i++;
        channel.basicPublish(message.getMessageProperties().getReceivedExchange(), message.getMessageProperties().getReceivedRoutingKey(),
                props.build(), message.getBody());
    }
    }
```

Comment: Not sure who recommended you to mark this question with `jms` tag, but that isn't correct. That is only about RabbitMQ. And yes, `spring-amqp`. Fixing...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all looks like you don't follow with the [Scheduling Messages with RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2015/04/16/scheduling-messages-with-rabbitmq/) article:

> To use the Delayed Message Exchange you just need to declare an exchange providing the "x-delayed-message" exchange type as follows:

```
Map<String, Object> args = new HashMap<String, Object>();
args.put("x-delayed-type", "direct");
channel.exchangeDeclare("my-exchange", "x-delayed-message", true, false, args);
```

I'd say the same can be achieved with the Spring AMQP:

```
@Bean
CustomExchange delayExchange() {
    Map<String, Object> args = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    args.put("x-delayed-type", "direct");
    return new CustomExchange("my-exchange", "x-delayed-message", true, false, args);
}
```

Another concern that you really should publish messages to that `delay-exchange`, not any other. Again: that is mentioned in that doc anyway.

**UPDATE**

Since Spring AMQP 1.6 the Delayed Messages is supported as out-of-the-box feature:
 https://spring.io/blog/2016/02/16/spring-amqp-1-6-0-milestone-1-and-1-5-4-available.

Comment: Yes, I was not getting this x-delayed-message type in Exchange as it was not in the Spring AMQP. I went through that many times but not able to figure out that it is a Exchange type. Anyways, I am able to do it now.

Comment: @Artem where should I look for spring-rabbit-1.6.xsd

Comment: Not sure what is your question, but `spring-rabbit-1.6.xsd` is fully a part of `spring-rabbit-1.6.0.RELEASE.jar`: `org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/config/spring-rabbit-1.6.xsd`. If you use versionless XSD declaration in your configs, you already can declare `delayed` attribute on exchanges definitions.

Comment: @ArtemBilan I have this in my config xml "http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit/spring-rabbit.xsd" but it doesn't work !!

Comment: @ArtemBilan though "http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit/spring-rabbit-1.5.xsd" this url works but it doesn't allow to use delayed attribute.

Comment: @ArtemBilan did this "classpath:org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/config/spring-rabbit-1.6.xsd" and it seems to be working. Is it the right way to pick xsd from within a jar ?

Comment: @lalit : please use like this
http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit 
    classpath:org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/config/spring-rabbit-1.6.xsd