# How to public message with delay time rabbitmq implement in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq

My case. I have queue container element with exactly time to deliver.
I use rabbitmq implement by spring boot to support. Now i should send message to queue and after delay time queue will deliver message. Rabbitmq support rabbitmq-delayed-message-exchange plugin to schedule message. But i do not implement . What wrong in my code. (I enabled plugin delay)

```
@Bean
DirectExchange directExchange() {
    Map<String, Object> args = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    args.put("x-delayed-type", "x-delayed-message");
    return new DirectExchange("my-exchange", true, false, args);
}

@Bean
Binding binding(Queue queue, DirectExchange directExchange) {
    return BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(directExchange).with(queueName);
}
```

The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Answer (score 20):

See the similar question with an appropriate answer.

[Scheduled/Delay messaging in Spring AMQP RabbitMq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35227845/scheduled-delay-messaging-in-spring-amqp-rabbitmq)

Your problem is here:

```
@Bean
CustomExchange delayExchange() {
    Map<String, Object> args = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    args.put("x-delayed-type", "direct");
    return new CustomExchange("my-exchange", "x-delayed-message", true, false, args);
}
```

From other side we have introduced the Delayed Exchange in the Spring AMQP 1.6: https://spring.io/blog/2016/02/16/spring-amqp-1-6-0-milestone-1-and-1-5-4-available.

**UPDATE**

The `Binding` should be declared as :

```
@Bean
Binding binding(Queue queue, Exchange delayExchange) {
    return BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(delayExchange).with("foo").noargs();
}
```

To send message with the `delay` you should do almost the same what you have tried:

```
rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend("my-exchange", "spring-boot", new DaoDoa(), new MessagePostProcessor() {
        @Override
        public Message postProcessMessage(Message message) throws AmqpException {
            message.getMessageProperties().setHeader("x-delay, 15000);
            return message;
        }
    });
```

Comment: it ok. Thanks for master. I passing it the last day and your solution is like me :D.

Comment: OK. That's great! Would like to see an accept for my answer. Otherwise all this discussion does not make sense here.

Comment: now you can add header by: ```message.getMessageProperties().setDelay(15000)```