# Delay message to send to listener using Spring AMQP

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I have a requirement to send message to MessageListener after certain duration , So is there any way to achieve using Spring AMQP.

Eg . 
Producer produces the message and message goes to RabbitMQ Q , The message gets received Listener listening to that Q immediately, I want to delay that message to be received at consumer side say after some configuration parameter say 1000ms

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The RabbitMQ provides for this purpose [Delayed Exchange](https://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2015/04/16/scheduling-messages-with-rabbitmq/) feature.

Starting with version 1.6 Spring AMQP also provides a high level API on the matter: http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/_reference.html#delayed-message-exchange:

```
<rabbit:topic-exchange name="topic" delayed="true" />
```

---

```
MessageProperties properties = new MessageProperties();
properties.setDelay(15000);
template.send(exchange, routingKey,
        MessageBuilder.withBody("foo".getBytes()).andProperties(properties).build());
```

**UPDATE**

Before Spring AMQP `1.6` you should do like this:

```
@Bean
CustomExchange delayExchange() {
    Map<String, Object> args = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    args.put("x-delayed-type", "direct");
    return new CustomExchange("my-exchange", "x-delayed-message", true, false, args);
}

...

MessageProperties properties = new MessageProperties();
properties.setHeader("x-delay", 15000);
template.send(exchange, routingKey,
        MessageBuilder.withBody("foo".getBytes()).andProperties(properties).build());
```

Also see this question and its answer: [Scheduled/Delay messaging in Spring AMQP RabbitMq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35227845/scheduled-delay-messaging-in-spring-amqp-rabbitmq)

Comment: Is this available in 1.4 version ?

Comment: What is the question? I said: since 1.6. Can you explain the reason to stick with such an old EOL version?

Comment: We will definitely be upgrading to latest version but after sometime( 2 months ) as we have a different product roll out strategy , So getting back to this problem so as we are developing this feature and we have amqp 1.4.3 , So is there any way we can achieve in this version or else we will have to wait for the upgrade in our product

Comment: I'll share with you something tomorrow. Yes, there is definitely a trick to deal with Delayed Exchange even without that Spring high level API

Comment: Please, find an *UPDATE* in my answer

Answer (score 3):

If you use spring boot, it can be like this:

```
@Bean
Queue queue() {
    return QueueBuilder.durable(queueName)
            .withArgument("x-dead-letter-exchange", dlx)
            .withArgument("x-dead-letter-routing-key", dlq)
            .build();
}


@Bean
TopicExchange exchange() {
    return (TopicExchange) ExchangeBuilder.topicExchange(topicExchangeName)
            .delayed()
            .build();

@Bean
Binding binding() {
    return BindingBuilder.bind(queue()).to(exchange()).with(queueName);
}
```