# Producer/Consumer Spring sending multiple messages

Tags: java, rabbitmq

I'm having a problem with producer consumer rabbitmq spring application. I want to send an array of messages from the producer to the consumer, the producer sends them however the consumer part doesn't receive them. When I tried to send only one message it worked. The code is below:

Producer method:

```
public void produce1(List<Company> companiesList){
        for (Company company:
             companiesList) {
            amqpTemplate.convertAndSend(exchange, routingkey, company);
            System.out.println("Send msg = " + company);
        }
       
    }
```

Consumer method:

```
 @RabbitListener(queues="${jsa.rabbitmq.queue}", containerFactory="jsaFactory")
    public void recievedMessage(Company company) {
        System.out.println("Recieved Message: " + company);
    }
```

What I want to do is get a list of companies and from that list send a company message to the consumer each one second. (so the delay between messages should be of one second)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this, convertAndSend(Object) takes any Object.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/latest-ga/api/org/springframework/amqp/core/AmqpTemplate.html

Therefore, you are sending 1 (Company) and your recievedMessage(Company) also expects 1 Company object, and that is why it works with 1.

If you want to send a batch(List) of Companies, then according to https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/2.2.9.RELEASE/reference/html/#receiving-batch you will need to setBatch and setBatchListener(true) and other configurations to support batch processing (Ability to send more than 1 message at a time)

convertAndSend(List xxx) and recievedMessage(List<Company) xxx)

Comment: I kind of written the wrong requirement, the thing is that I want to send messages from an array, and each message to be sent at one second, will I still be using the batch?

Comment: Hello @simm you will not send an array.  You will send a List<Company> instead and if you want to send (>1 Company), meaning you want to send many companies at once, then it is batch yes.

If my under does not fit your question, then kindly clarify your question with examples and what it is exactly you want to achieve

Comment: and I know that it's not related to the initial question, but I can't seem to find where to implement a delay between sending the companies of one second? is there a batch function for that?--I also edited my question and clarified it in the last row

Comment: @Simm Kindly see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40634830/delay-message-to-send-to-listener-using-spring-amqp  It might help you, otherwise I believe you should just read further documentation.  I dont know of the exact configurations.

Another option which is I am against and you are desperate is to sleep

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1); 

I prefer if you spent the time reading the documentation to see the option of setting message delay.